# what are the post parameter in this post request

Tags: http, post, http-post, httprequest

I have a page that I can get by GET request.

the response of that request is an html page that has a button called `Search`

when I called that button, a post request is fired and get response that is appended to the page. In other words, clicking on that button didn't give me a completely new page but It adds new content to that page.

I tried to use `Live HTTP headers` firefox extension to read the request in order to see the parameters that are being sent in the post request. This is what I get

```
POST /plugins/ad/buy.php?q=used+cars+dubai HTTP/1.1
Host: www.autodealer.ae
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.autodealer.ae/plugins/ad/buy.php?q=used+cars+dubai
Cookie: PHPSESSID=f2072a947619ef2d61b552f38e163d02; __utma=154876456.960352407.1397595567.1397595567.1397598041.2; __utmc=154876456; __utmz=154876456.1397595567.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __gads=ID=7a5bda3c29913b41:T=1397595570:S=ALNI_MZg2J44DRK3D1j8CX4FpZWFHWIzuw; __utmb=154876456.1.10.1397598041
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 131
vehcategory=All&make=All&model=&platename=&pricefrom=%3C500&priceto=All&city=All&sort=postdate&results_listing=1MONTH&Search=Search
```

I have read many questions on StackOverFlow website and I learned that the post parameters exit in the request body. and in my situation, the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so the post parameters should be as a `query string`

#### My Question

where is the post parameters in the above request? I just can see the cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP GET Parameters are in the query string.

HTTP POST would have them inside the content body - so looks as though they are:

```
   Content-Length: 131

vehcategory=All&make=All&model=&platename=&pricefrom=%3C500&priceto=All&city=All&sort=postdate&results_listing=1MONTH&Search=Search
```